# Link directly to reputation and badges pages on site profiles from the accounts list

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

I'll start this by saying that I have accounts on multiple SE sites, although Stack Overflow is the only one that I use *frequently*. However, I do make use of the accounts section on the summary tab of my profile to occasionally check for rep changes on my top five accounts.

Clicking the name of the site on this list brings me to the summary tab of that SE site, but I'm left wondering why clicking my reputation/badges for this site doesn't take me directly to the appropriate tab on that site. Here's a picture to further demonstrate what I mean.

[image]

Sure I could just click Meta, or Ask Different and then take the one extra step to navigate myself to the rep/badge tab, so this feature being added wouldn't exactly be a huge deal. It sure would be convenient though! Thoughts?

Comment: The rep link would be useful - if you suddenly notice you've got 50 rep more than you recall, it will take you directly to the list of changes.

Comment: I've always thought it links there, just never tried it. Now, I want it too!