# Click badges > link to badges, click reputation > link to reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges, hyperlinks, user-card

Right now user ava-cards only link to their profile page if you click their name.  I suggest clicking the badges links to user/Badges, and clicking their reputation links to user/reputation.

[image]

I'm often interested in badges for some reason, and it's a click-scroll-click thing from a user's ava-card, where it could just be a single click easily.

Interestingly from the user profile page, reputation score already links to rep.

[image]

It seems reasonable that badge displays and rep on the user card also link to their respective pages.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163413/13295